# swift - background music and segues

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, playback

I've currently got a game I'm working on, the game consists of three view controllers: `GameIntroViewController` `GameViewController` `GameOverViewController`.

Each view controller is linked by a push `segue`.  using the following method...

`GameIntroViewController` button -> `GameViewController` programmatically -> `GameOverViewController` button -> `GameViewController` and so on....

I've currently set up the app to start playing the background music in my `GameIntroViewController`, this works well however the music surprisingly re-starts with each segue, whilst this isn't a problem I'd like the music to not restart but continue as if it is one track uninterrupted by segues.

Ultimately I need the music to either pause or stop when `GameOverViewController` is shown as the music clashes with any video adverts that then play. Would anyone know the best way to do this?

Thinking about it it would be great to have different music on the `GameIntroViewController` and the `GameViewController` and then no music on the `GameOverViewController`.  Any ideas how I can achieve this without the music playing over the top of one another?

Here is my code so far..... (all in `GameIntroViewController`)

```
import AVFoundation

class GameIntroViewController: UIViewController {

var backgroundMusicPlayer:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}


override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    var bgMusicURL:NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("bgMusic", withExtension: "m4a")!
    backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: bgMusicURL, error: nil)
    backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
    backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
}
```

Thank you to anyone who can help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently creating a new AVAudioPlayer object every time a new controller is initialized:

```
class GameIntroViewController: UIViewController {
    var backgroundMusicPlayer:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
}
```

You should make your AVAudioPlayer object global, and set it up once. Like so:

```
var backgroundMusicPlayer:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

class GameIntroViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var bgMusicURL:NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("bgMusic", withExtension: "m4a")!
        backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: bgMusicURL, error: nil)
        backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
        backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

Also very important to note: **ONLY setup the backgroundMusicPlayer ONCE in your GameIntroViewController's viewDidLoad**. Otherwise, it will be reinitialized whenever this controller lays out it's views. If you setup this object in the other controllers, it will reset the object as well.

This method of doing this also allows you to play and pause the backgroundMusicPlayer from anywhere in the application.

good luck,

ZR

Comment: Thank you so much that worked! Would you know what I could add to my `GameOverViewController` to mute the background music automatically?

Comment: on viewWillAppear place the code: backgroundMusicPlayer.pause() OR (to mute) do: backgroundMusicPlayer.volume = 0

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like the music to not restart but continue as if it is one track uninterrupted by segues

Since you want the music to continue even as view controllers come and go, it stands to reason that managing the music from your view controllers is the wrong way to go. Instead, create some other controller-type object to manage the music (including the audio player, the list of tracks to be played, etc.). Create your "music controller" early in the app and pass it from one view controller to the next, as you would a model object. Maybe even better, you could make the list of tracks to play part of the app's data model so that view controllers could influence the upcoming music tracks simply by interacting with the model -- they'd never even need to know about the music controller.